# Move Table Row on dynamically created row?

Tags: jquery, row

When I dynamically created table row using Jquery. I found I can not move the new created row using js. On the other hand, I can move the already created rows using Jquery.
Please see the [Demo in jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/TdsLj/2/)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method:

```
$(".up,.down").live('click',function(){
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TdsLj/3/

By definition live() will "Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."

Comment: Thanks jyoseph. Could you please expain why can't I catch the click event in the original code? Why can not catch the event from the "future" element? Thanks!

Comment: Because at the time the page is loaded, the .up and .down links all have handlers. When you add another .up and/or .down to the dom, those do not have handlers. Using live() will match any existing or future elements (future meaning, adding to the dom like you are). Hope that helps!